# Notification email: Who is the sender?

Tags: email, opportunity

When changing the owner of an Opportunity, we have the possibility to check the checkbox "Send Notification Email".

[image]

My question is quite simple: Who will be the sender of this mail?

Currently, it's really strange, because the sender of this email is a user that left our enterprise a few years ago, and I didn't find any trace of this user in our system (account was deleted, etc.). So I wonder from where Salesforce gets this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

First, users cannot have their account "deleted." Users exist always and forever. I suspect that the user was "recycled" (the details of the original user were overwritten with the new user), and the old user's settings are still hanging out in Setup. For this reason, it is absolutely *vital* that you never recycle users.

Second, the Send Notification Email can't be configured. It always behaves the same way. The *current user* is the sender of the email, using a predefined template that cannot be modified.

My guess is that the email is the personal settings for the user (Your Name > Settings/My Settings > Email > My Email Settings). You can configure your display name and email address here, which may be different than the First Name, Last Name, and Email address of the user.

In the future, **do not** recycle users. The system only counts active users against your license count, so there's no legitimate reason for changing a user this way.

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately I was not able to change these information with my Administrator Account, I had to ask the new -recycled- owner of this account to update these information. Thanks !